# Not allowing assigning identical types

Tags: go

I have defined the types here identically, yet I get an error on compilation:

> cannot use questions (type []struct { Question questions.MasterQuestion }) as type []struct { Question questions.MasterQuestion "json:"question"" } in assignment
> i

Here is my code:

> types file

```
type QuestionnaireInternal struct {
    ID            string                `json:"id"`
    Questionnaire InternalQuestionnaire `json:"questionnaire"`
    Questions     []struct {
        Question MasterQuestion `json:"question"`
    } `json:"questions"`
}
```

> DAL file

```
qusIdxMap := make(map[string]struct{})
    var questions []struct {Question questions.MasterQuestion}

    for {

        buf := idRows.NextBytes()
        if len(buf) == 0 {
            break
        }

        var ids []string
        if de := json.Unmarshal(buf, &ids); de != nil {
            return nil, de
        }

        for i := range ids {
            if _, exists := qusIdxMap[ids[i]]; exists == false {
                qusIdxMap[ids[i]] = struct{}{}
            }
        }

        for j := range qus.Questions {
            if _, exists := qusIdxMap[qus.Questions[j].Question.QuestionID]; exists {
                *ERROR HERE:* **questions = append(questions, &qus.Questions[j])**
            }
        }
        qus.Questions = questions
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two structs are in fact not identical.

According to the Go specs, field tags participate in [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) (emphasis mine):

> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, **and identical tags**. Non-exported field names from different packages are always different.

Since you are using anonymous structs, you have to add the same tag to the `questions` var declaration:

```
var questions []struct {Question questions.MasterQuestion `json:"question"`}
```

---

Or you can define a `Question` type:

```
type QuestionnaireInternal struct {
    ID            string                `json:"id"`
    Questionnaire InternalQuestionnaire `json:"questionnaire"`
    Questions     []Question            `json:"questions"`
}

type Question struct {
    Question MasterQuestion `json:"question"`
}
```

and then

```
var questions []Question
```